# Что могло случиться с wedbriverio?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, jasmine

Пытаюсь запустить тесты на Jasmine через chimp.js, но прохождение тестов фейлится с ошибкой:

```
Expected function not to throw, but it threw ReferenceError: browser is not defined.
```

Код теста примерно такой:

```
browser.url('http://localhost:30552/');
it("should be able to click Signin button after fill credentils", function() {
    expect(function() {
        console.log(browser);
        browser.setValue('[name=email]', credentials.login);
        browser.setValue('[name=password]', credetials.password);

        browser.submitForm('#signInForm');
    }).not.toThrow();
});
```

Чего не хватает? Что нужно установить что бы добавить определение для browser?